# Openlayers3: incorrect image tile size

Tags: openlayers

This is my code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [ 
        new ol.layer.Tile({source : new ol.source.OSM()}),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            extent: [902139.70, 4699598.09, 1095989.85, 5063669.03], // in EPSG:3857
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://webgis.regione.sardegna.it/tms/ortofoto2006_EPSG3003/{z}/{x}/{-y}.jpg',
                projection: 'EPSG:3003',
                tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                    extent: [1422280, 4300042.99999999068677, 1570760, 4577639.99999999068677],
                    resolutions: [0.5,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048],
                    tileSize: [256,256]
                }),
            })
        }),
    ],
    target : 'map',
    view : new ol.View({
        center: [902139.70, 4699598.09],
        zoom: 7
    })
});
```

The result: Sardinia is 1/2 of the real size.

Did I forget something?

[image: Code rendered]

Comment: Openlayers can't handle EPSG: 3003 natively, you will need to using a library like Proj4 to use this projection, once your have done that you need to add projection: EPSG3003 to your view statement. I'm not near my computer at the moment but I will post a full answer later, if no one else has.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Really, in my project, I used Proj4 to define 'EPSG:3003' projection.
I think my problem is the origins of my images:
In OpenLayers 3, the origin of a tiled image would be in the top left corner, but in my images the origin is in bottom left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify your own resolutions you should use ol.tilegrid.TileGrid instead of createXYZ.  Also the array should be in descending order.

```
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: [1422280, 4300042.99999999068677, 1570760, 4577639.99999999068677],
            resolutions: [2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1,0.5],
            tileSize: [256,256]
        }),
```

I've just tried that and Sardina was the right size but in the wrong place.  That was because using {-y} only works properly when your extent is the same size as the top 0/0/0 tile.  In other cases you can set the origin and use a tileUrlFunctiuon.

```
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            projection: 'EPSG:3003',
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                extent: [1422280, 4300042.99999999068677, 1570760, 4577639.99999999068677],
                origin: [1422280, 4300042.99999999068677],
                resolutions: [2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1,0.5],
                tileSize: [256,256]
            }),
            tileUrlFunction: function (coordinate) { 
                return 'http://webgis.regione.sardegna.it/tms/ortofoto2006_EPSG3003/' +
                       coordinate[0] + '/' + coordinate[1] + '/' + coordinate[2] + ".jpg"
            }
        })
```

[image]